# How to find the solution of nonhomogenous system with no initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Let 
$$y^{\prime}=A\,y+g$$

Where $A$ is some $3$ by $3$ matrix and $g$ is $3$ dimensional vector and $-\infty<t<\infty$. I know how to solve this question if I was given $y(t_0)$.

However in a question I am trying to answer I am not given any initial condition.

I have already found the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ and solved the homogeneous part. But I don't know  how to continue to the non-homogeneous part with no condition given. Is there away around this.

Thanks,

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $t$ so $y'=y'(t)$?

Comment: The general solution is the sum of a particular solution and the general solution of the homogenous problem where $g=0$.